autoinstall w/ LVM & LUKS: autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 using autoinstall on an UEFI-based Intel NUC w/ LVM + LUKS. Unfortunately, the installation aborts with the error:
autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition
My config looks like this:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  update: true
  apt:
    mirror-selection:
      primary:
        - country-mirror
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-noble
    password: ***
    username: ***
  packages:
    - cryptsetup
    - cryptsetup-initramfs
    - dropbear-initramfs
    - lvm2
    - python3
  ssh:
    install-server: true
  source:
    id: ubuntu-server-minimal
  storage:
    swap:
      size: 0
    config:
    - id: primary-disk
      type: disk
      grub_device: false
      ptable: gpt
      preserve: false
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      match:
        size: smallest

    - id: partition-efi
      type: partition
      size: 1G
      device: primary-disk
      flag: boot
      partition_type: EF00
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      grub_device: true
      number: 1
    - id: partition-boot
      type: partition
      size: 2G
      device: primary-disk
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      number: 2
    - id: partition-luks
      type: partition
      size: -1
      device: primary-disk
      number: 3
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false

    - id: luks
      type: dm_crypt
      volume: partition-luks
      key: ***
      preserve: false

    - id: lvm_vg0
      name: vg0
      devices:
      - luks
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
    - id: lvm_partition-root
      name: root
      volgroup: lvm_vg0
      size: -1
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition

    - id: efi-format
      type: format
      fstype: fat32
      volume: partition-efi
      label: EFI
    - id: boot-format
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-boot
      label: boot
    - id: root-format
      type: format
      fstype: btrfs
      volume: lvm_partition-root
      label: root

    - id: boot-mount
      type: mount
      path: /boot
      device: partition-boot
      format: ext4
    - id: efi-mount
      type: mount
      path: /boot/efi
      device: partition-efi
      format: fat32
    - id: root-mount
      type: mount
      path: /
      device: lvm_partition-root
      format: btrfs
      options: 'noatime,discard,compress=zstd:1'

Any hints what's wrong with my config are much appreciated!
I found ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall storage section , "autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition", but the proposed solution is IMHO already implemented in my config
